# Wcf TimeoutException

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, timeoutexception

I create WCF application that used Azure Cloud Service.
**Sometimes client catch TimeoutException About 3 times a day.**
Now, Total of client amounts about 100 clients.So The 100 cleint access wcf server at the same time.
The setting is below.How do I optimize? or Do I mistake?

1. WorkerRols.cs

   ```
   ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = Int32.MaxValue;
   var netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
   netTcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
   netTcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
   netTcpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 314572800;
   netTcpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 20971520;
   netTcpBinding.MaxBufferSize = 20971520;
   netTcpBinding.ListenBacklog = 2147483647;
   netTcpBinding.MaxConnections = 2147483647;
   netTcpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
   //binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0);
   //binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0);
   netTcpBinding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;
   netTcpBinding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
   ServiceThrottlingBehavior throttle;
   throttle = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceThrottlingBehavior>();
   if (throttle == null)
   {
           LogWriter.PutInfo(CLASSNAME, "throttle == null");
           throttle = new ServiceThrottlingBehavior();
           throttle.MaxConcurrentCalls = Int32.MaxValue;
           throttle.MaxConcurrentSessions = Int32.MaxValue;
           throttle.MaxConcurrentInstances = Int32.MaxValue;
           host.Description.Behaviors.Add(throttle);
   }
   ```
2. app.config

   ```
   <system.net>
           <connectionManagement>
                   <add address="*" maxconnection="65535"/>
           </connectionManagement>
   </system.net>
   ```

Comment: what does your service inner code do? is the azure worker role instance using it's max allocated resources (see the stats in azure management portal, maybe you have peaks of usage and you need to create many instances to handle them)?

Comment: The CPU average is 7-8%.I think the resource has an available capacity.

Comment: What if the jobs that the clients consume take too long for some reason  (I see you set the timeout to 1 minute)? The clients get time-outs running specific actions or in general?

Comment: I assume you expose the WCF's using an IISHost app actually, if so have you set the <httpRuntime executionTimeout="36000"/> ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I set sendtimeout as 10 sec. Because Client almost gets return message under 1 second.